# same buttons with same effects - jquery OOP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, oop

how can I give my buttons same effect? since they are all the same. But what i wanted to do is to have a "soul-like" verification when i clicked them.

**My code in php**

```
echo "<form action='receipt.php?name=$name' method='post'>
        <input style='position:absolute; top:$this->yForBuy; left:$this->xForBuy; z-index:4;' type='button' id='btnSubmit' value='Purchase'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='bidder' value='$name'>
        <input type='hidden' name='item_no' value='$no'>
        <input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='$itname'>
        <input type='hidden' name='item_price' value='$bid'>
        </form>";

<label id='soul' style='position:absolute; z-index:5; color:black;'>purchased!</label>
```

**this is my code in js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#soul").hide();

    $("#btnSubmit").click(function()
    {
        var position = $(this).position();
        var topTo = position.top-10;
        alert("position: "+position.top+"\n new position:"+topTo);
        $("#soul")
            .css({'top' : topTo , 'left' : position.left, 'display' : 'block'})
            .show();


    });




 });
```

if you im using an OOP structure here that's why i have multiple buttons with same functionality. I struggle in the javascript part and i don't know how i ca do it.

[image]

Comment: what does 'soul-like' verification mean?

Comment: in the .animate() part, when the button is clicked there's a text going up and at the same time its fading out. :P sorry for my explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The id attribute should be unique on the page and not repeated for each button.
The JS cannot handle the fact that `#btnSubmit` appears more than once..

if the code is being generated by a php loop then you may need to implement a numbering of the ids.. `#btnSubmit1`, `#btnSubmit2`, etc..

Either add a class to the button and use that as the common selector or try out [HTML5 data attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/):

```
echo "<form action='receipt.php?name=$name' method='post'>
        <input style='position:absolute; top:$this->yForBuy; left:$this->xForBuy; z-index:4;' type='button' class='purchaseButton' value='Purchase'/>
        <input type='hidden' name='bidder' value='$name'>
        <input type='hidden' name='item_no' value='$no'>
        <input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='$itname'>
        <input type='hidden' name='item_price' value='$bid'>
        </form>";

<label id='soul' style='position:absolute; z-index:5; color:black;'>purchased!</label>
```

then:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#soul").hide();

    $(".purchaseButton").click(function()
    {
        var position = $(this).position();
        var topTo = position.top-10;
        alert("position: "+position.top+"\n new position:"+topTo);
        $("#soul")
            .css({'top' : topTo , 'left' : position.left, 'display' : 'block'})
            .show();
    });
 });
```

in order to animate, include an id attribute for the form (again must be unique)
`<form action='receipt.php?name=$name' id='FORMID' method='post'>`

then in the js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#soul").hide();

        $(".purchaseButton").click(function()
        {
            var position = $(this).position();
            var topTo = position.top-10;
            alert("position: "+position.top+"\n new position:"+topTo);
            $("#soul")
                .css({'top' : topTo , 'left' : position.left, 'display' : 'block'})
                .show();
            $('#WHATEVER').animate({
               // whatever options here..
               complete: function() { 
               // this will run after the animation has finished
               $('#FORMID').submit(); // manually submit the form
               }
            });
        });
     });
```

Comment: btw, how can i .animate() first before submitting the form?

Comment: Instead of having a `type="submit"` you can perform the necessary animation in the `.click` event then just call `$('#FORMID').submit();` (you will need to add an `id=""` to the form html.